# Why does apk add wget give me code 2 error?

Tags: docker, wget, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I am running the following in my docker file

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache wget
```

I get the following error

> 2 errors; 14 distinct packages available
> ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add
> --no-cache wget] exit code 2 Service 'cron' Failed to build

Is this command correct?

Comment: It works for me when I try to reproduce. My build command is `docker build -t test .` Try doing `docker pull alpine:latest` to make sure you have the newest version of the image.